# How to get specific table id to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, inline

I have many rows of data. Each row has 3 cells - id, eesnimi, perenimi. I want to be able to inline edit all of the cells. I am using [In place editor](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/).

How can I get specific cells (the cell I am editing at the moment) `id` to javascript (element_id field), so I know which element to change in mysql.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".editme1").editInPlace({
        url: 'http://localhost/petka/kast.php',
        element_id: ??????,
        show_buttons: true
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <?PHP
        $sql="SELECT * FROM nimed";
        $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
        WHILE ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))  {
            echo '<tr class="row">';
            echo '<td class="editme1" id="id|'.$row["id"].'" title="id">'.$row["id"].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="editme1" id="eesnimi|'.$row["id"].'" title="eesnimi">'.$row["eesnimi"].'</td>';
            echo '<td class="editme1" id="perenimi|'.$row["id"].'" title="perenimi">'.$row["perenimi"].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Just as an aside, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and prone to injection attacks.  Use [php data objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used

```
 $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".editme1").editInPlace({
  url: 'http://localhost/petka/kast.php',
  element_id: $(this).attr("id"),
  show_buttons: true
 });
});
```